# Why is the `std` module undeclared?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to read a single character from `stdin`, but I can't get it working. In different program, I used this exact same method and it worked.

```
let mut buffer = [0];
let _ = std::io::stdin().read(&mut buffer);
let a = buffer[0];
```

Compiling it gives this error:

```
src/befunge.rs:220:17: 220:31 error: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module `std::io` [E0433]
src/befunge.rs:220      let _ = std::io::stdin().read(&mut buffer);
```

Comment: When asking questions on SO, please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible, so that answers can be objectively checked to solve the issue. For your example, this could be [this simple program](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=43e3a4de6103ca986767bd304f54fe5e&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I assume that `befunge.rs` is not your crate root, but a submodule. Paths like `std::io::stdin()` that are used outside of a `use ...;` declaration are relative to the current module, not absolute. To make the path absolute, **prefix `::`** (like a prefixed `/` in unix paths) -> `::std::io::stdin()`. Alternatively you can `use` some part of the path, like:

```
use std;
std::io::stdin();
```

or

```
use std::io;
io::stdin();
```

If you are using a subpath, like `std::io` more than once in your module, it's usually best to `use` it at the top.

If you are in the crate root, there is no difference between `::std` and `std`, because the relative lookup path is the root. It only matters in submodules. Also: paths in `use` declarations are always absolute -- to make them relative to the current module prefix `self::`.

Comment: I have a new problem with it that these solutions don't fix. I edited the main post.

Comment: Please ask only one question per SO-thread. So you should in theory create a separate question for your edit. But: this question has already been answered on SO, so better search for that. Spoiler: just read the whole error message of the compiler (including the note).

Comment: Do we have rationale in making "use" different, which is absolute, instead of relative to the current module?